# How to resolve error 403() while using Youtube API Key for search?

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

While use API Key in my code but i'm getting these errors when i search and page load.....
[image: Screenshoot of inspect console]

[image: Error geting when click on error link 403()]

Here is my code

```js
var gapikey = 'MYKEY';


$(function() {
    
    // call fancybox pluggin
    $(".fancyboxIframe").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 900,
        maxHeight    : 600,
        fitToView    : false,
        width        : '90%',
        height        : '90%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick    : false,
        openEffect    : 'none',
        closeEffect    : 'none',
        iframe: {
            scrolling : 'auto',
            preload   : true
        }
    });
    
    $('#search-form').submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function searchYoutube() {
    // clear 
    $('#results').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>');
    $('#buttons').html('');
    
    // get form input
    q = $('#search').val();  // this probably shouldn't be created as a global
    
    // run get request on API
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: q,
            type: 'video',
            key: gapikey
        }, function(data) {
            var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
            var prevPageToken = data.prevPageToken;
            
            // Log data
            console.log(data);
            $('#results').html('');
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                
                // Get Output
                var output = getOutput(item);
                
                // display results
                $('#results').append(output);
            });
            
            var buttons = getButtons(prevPageToken, nextPageToken);
            
            // Display buttons
            $('#buttons').append(buttons);
        });
}
```

I am confused and don't able to resolve issue.You Can?I create my search engine but due to this i am not getting required result from my engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a referrer, that s allowed to access the Google Api. This referrer is set at http://console.developers.google.com and it must be equal to the site that does the request. So you need to change the referrer or you need to change the server domain.

The easiest would be to set the refferrer to * wich means *all*.

Comment: @ShahzaibChadhar youre welcome. please tick the green checkmark to close this thread ;)